# Is there a way to pass a secret Heroku environment variable in my Django project to a static Javascript file?

Tags: python, django, security, heroku

I don't have a lot of website experience. I'm trying to get my site up and running.

I have a secret environment variable on my Heroku app that I want to pass into a static file. Is there a way to do this securely? I've decided I don't care if bad actors can see the file, I just don't want them seeing the key.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. How is your project set up?

**Are you able to modify the js file?**
You can write a function that sends a xhr request to your django server and the server sends the env variable value as result.

**Is the static js file stored with your django backend?**
You can parse and then write the file with the env var value. If you know the structure you can put it in appropriate scope, otherwise you can just put a global const varname = env_value or document.varname = env_value at the top of your file (This is not ideal)

Comment: I am able to edit the file. But if I make a request to the Django server, won't anybody be able to mimic that request?

Comment: You can hide the route behind some kind of authorization if you're using protected routes already. If not, you can send some kind of auth data (a jwt token, or file hash, or another form of secret) that the server can validate.

Since you can edit the file, you can have the server modify it on server start - that would be much simpler. However if your value changes while the server is still running, you will need to handle refresh/errors for existing users the js file has been served to

Comment: How would I have the server modify the file. Do you have a resource you could share on that. That would be great, thanks!